# if you want to use reanimated 2 then go through your installation

Tags: react-native

I'm having a problem with a component that takes the state of another component after deleting the first one.
I'm trying to debug my React Native application but when I use the "Debug with Chrome" option, the app crashes and I get an error: `if you want to use reanimated 2 then go through your installation`

The problem is that I went through the installation and I already installed it.

This is my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

I have this line in my package.json:

```
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
```

under "dependencies".

and I also did `pod install` in the iOS directory.
I tried to reinstall node_modules and to reinstall the app (running on simulator)

When running the application not in Debug mode, it works fine, but only when trying to debug this error is presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enable debug mode with Reanimated 2. This happens because Reanimated 2 uses [Turbo Modules](https://formidable.com/blog/2019/fabric-turbomodules-part-3/), that have this limitation that doesn't allow you to use debug mode.
You can use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) for debugging instead

Answer (score 0):

For me I had created my project two years ago before react native switched to a Swift.  I rebuilt my project using a new react-native init and copying my info and .m files over.